# Theming color attributes in Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce

After much tinkering I finally could install images as color attributes in Kickstart.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHn1h.png

**Several problems:**

> 1. Images do not display their own titles, but the field name.
> 2. I do not need the product variations title.
> 3. I need image attributes displayed in rows of 10, in small expandable thumbnails, I should be able to use colorbox or Cloud Zoom
>      on them.

Please help.